# Overwrite the Knockout object

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I need to Overwrite the Knockout Object . But When  I try this I got the Following Error. When the Page Load I called loadXMLFiles and It worked without any issue. after pressing a button when I try to overwrite the object I got following Error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromJS' of undefined` in downloadFile Function. but in both Cases It's coming same object. Can Any one please help me on this???

```
var urlPath = window.location.pathname;
//var self = this;

$(function () {  
    ko.applyBindings(indexVM);

    indexVM.loadXMLFiles();
});



var indexVM = {
    XMLFiles: ko.observableArray([]),

    loadXMLFiles: function () {

        var self = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../HotelBackEndProcess/UpdateDatabase/FillIndex",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {               
                self.XMLFiles(data);

            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
            }
        });       
    },
    DownloadFile: function () {   
    Id = this.Id;
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../HotelBackEndProcess/UpdateDatabase/DownloadFile",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: { Id: Id },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {               

            ko.mapping.fromJS(XMLFiles, self.data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
        }
    }); 
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably missing the `mapping` plugin (which has to be downloaded separately):

See [ko.mapping](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/tree/master/build/output) in GitHub.

Comment: I have download it but now I got the following Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__ko_mapping__' of undefined

Comment: I guess it's `self.data` that returns `undefined`. Try: `self.XMLFiles(ko.mapping.fromJS(data))`.

Comment: now I got the following error "undefined is not a function", in loadxmlfiles function I could able to use self.XMLfiles, but when I used it on DownloadFile Function I am getting error

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do on the `success` function? Which field you're trying to replace?

Comment: I need to change the download datetime field once click the button

Comment: Is that field part of the view-model? Where exactly?